# Azure functions java: How to read blob tags as part of blob trigger?

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-trigger

I am using blob trigger to read and process blobs from Azure storage container. Currently, it works fine, I am able to receive the blob content and process it using the annotations as shown below. Now I need to know how to read the blob tags and metadata as part of the input?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> I need to know how to read the blob tags and metadata as part of the input?

`metadata` and `tags` cannot be read from blob trigger or blob input binding. to get `metadata` and `tag` of the file you need to use `BlobServiceClient`.

This code worked for me.
**`Function.java`:**

```java
package com.function;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.*;
import com.azure.storage.blob.*;
import com.azure.storage.blob.models.*;

public class Function {
    @FunctionName("BlobTriggerJava1")
    @StorageAccount("AzureWebJobsStorage")
    public void run(
        @BlobTrigger(name = "content", path = "test/{name}",dataType = "String") String content,  
        @BindingName("name") String name,
        final ExecutionContext context
    ) {
        String connectionString = System.getenv("AzureWebJobsStorage");
        String containerName = "test";
        String blobName = name;

        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(connectionString).buildClient();

        BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient(containerName);

        BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(blobName);

        BlobProperties blobProperties = blobClient.getProperties();

        context.getLogger().info("The details of file "+name+" are:\n{\n\t Etag :"+blobProperties.getETag()+"\n\t metadata :"+blobProperties.getMetadata()+"\n}");
    }
}
```

Additional dependency in **`pom.xml`:**

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
            <version>12.25.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

**`OUTPUT`:**

[image]

```
Functions:

        BlobTriggerJava1: blobTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-01-25T10:02:31.162Z] Worker process started and initialized.
[2024-01-25T10:02:34.927Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000AAE5F384'.
[2024-01-25T10:02:57.214Z] Executing 'Functions.BlobTriggerJava1' (Reason='New blob detected(LogsAndContainerScan): metrics/hello.txt', Id=97ca72c1-d357-497c-bbc1-f47fd78308ea)
[2024-01-25T10:02:57.218Z] Trigger Details: MessageId: a6f20214-95da-4b65-ad3f-0322360d8904, DequeueCount: 1, InsertedOn: 2024-01-25T10:02:55.000+00:00, BlobCreated: 2024-01-25T09:52:43.000+00:00, BlobLastModified: 2024-01-25T10:02:50.000+00:00
[2024-01-25T10:02:59.319Z] The details of file hello.txt are:
{
         Etag :0x8DC1D8CCA4B5F11
         metadata :{}
}
[2024-01-25T10:02:59.319Z] Function "BlobTriggerJava1" (Id: 97ca72c1-d357-497c-bbc1-f47fd78308ea) invoked by Java Worker       
[2024-01-25T10:02:59.371Z] Executed 'Functions.BlobTriggerJava1' (Succeeded, Id=97ca72c1-d357-497c-bbc1-f47fd78308ea, Duration=2631ms)
```

[image]

Comment: I know we can use blobClient to pull metadata about a blob but that is an overkill.  I thought blob trigger or input binding might have such support. Anyway, thanks for detailed sample.

Comment: Unfortunately, currently option is not available in trigger and input binding.